# Shadow at the menu bar and dropdown

Tags: html, css

we use the plugin ubermenu and i want to add shadows below the menu bar and the dropdown, exactly like: nelly.se - our website is: http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket

I've been trying to add code:

```
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu{
  box-shadow:2px 2px 0px 0px #ccc;
}
```

but without any result :(

Comment: Ehm, the word `megaMenu` doesn't appear anywhere in your site's source.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code to apply a shadow effect on your submenu(dropdown)

```
.ubermenu-main .ubermenu-item-level-0 > .ubermenu-submenu-drop {
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

no your code is work may be you have to try different color

```
.ubermenu-main .ubermenu-item-level-0 > .ubermenu-submenu-drop {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
}
```

may be this is better than the before
[image]